# Who are on the field in a field goal or PAT situation in American football?

Tags: american-football, special-teams

In American football, a long snapper, a holder, and a kicker are required in a field goal or one-point conversion situation.

Who are the other eight players on the field in these situations? If most of the offensive team stay on the field, who are the three players that are removed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

8 big guys, who have one job: don't let the defense block the kick. There would be no *specific* overlap with the offensive starters (e.g. the starting left tackle wouldn't necessarily stay in to play left tackle), but obviously the skills that offensive linemen have are very closely related to the skills you want here.

Answer (score 0):

The first 2-3 (4-6 players total) on each side of the snapper are usually offensive linemen. The last player, or 2, on each side is usually player types that fit a Tight End mold. Large, strong players with blocking ability that are also more athletic and more likely to be able to catch (for fake kicks).

Outside of the linemen, they're not typical positions. Different teams call them different things based on the teams utilization of them (say between the OL and TE types).